# How to join two lists based on the names of items contained in both lists

Tags: r, list, join, data-wrangling

I want to join two lists in R based on the names of items within the list. For example I have 2 lists that have shared tibble names in them (1-3). I want to combine these lists so that there is one list that contains all of the information based on number (so the end product would be one list that has nested tibbles in it (2 tibbles for one, two tibbles for 2 etc). I also want to know how to do this if my starting point was lists within lists and I'm wanting to join them based on name (same concept, the list just contains named lists instead of named tibbles)

Thanks for your help.

```
`1` <- tibble(colA = c("AB", "AB", "BA", "BA"), colB = c("K", "K", "K", "K"), colC=c("TP", "TP", "ND", "ND") )
 `2` <- tibble(colA = c("CD", "AB", "BA", "BA"), colB = c("L", "L", "L", "L"), colC=c("TP", "ND", "ND", "ND") )
 `3` <- tibble(colA = c("CD", "AB", "BA"), colB = c("M", "M", "M"), colC=c("TP", "ND", "ND"))
 MyList1 <- list(`1`, `2`, `3`)
 MyList1
>  MyList1
[[1]]
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  colA  colB  colC 
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 AB    K     TP   
2 AB    K     TP   
3 BA    K     ND   
4 BA    K     ND   

[[2]]
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  colA  colB  colC 
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 CD    L     TP   
2 AB    L     ND   
3 BA    L     ND   
4 BA    L     ND   

[[3]]
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  colA  colB  colC 
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 CD    M     TP   
2 AB    M     ND   
3 BA    M     ND   

 
 `1` <- tibble(colA = c("AB", "AB"), colB = c("K", "K"), colC=c("TP", "ND") )
 `2` <- tibble(colA = c("CD"), colB = c("L"), colC=c("TP") )
 `3` <- tibble(colA = c("CD", "AB", "BA"), colB = c("M", "M", "M"), colC=c("TP", "ND", "ND"))
 MyList2 <- list(`1`, `2`, `3`)
 MyList2

>  MyList2
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  colA  colB  colC 
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 AB    K     TP   
2 AB    K     ND   

[[2]]
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  colA  colB  colC 
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 CD    L     TP   

[[3]]
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  colA  colB  colC 
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 CD    M     TP   
2 AB    M     ND   
3 BA    M     ND
```

Comment: Do you want `map2(MyList1, MyList2, bind_rows)` or in `base R` `Map(rbind, MyList1, MyList2)`.  BTW, your lists are not named.  If you want to name it, you have to specify as either `list(`1` = ..., `2` = ..., ...)`

Comment: I think this will combine the tibbles into one. Instead I want to keep the tibbles separate, but combine them into one list organized based on item name . The end product I desire is a list that contains 3 lists. Each of these nested lists contains the two separate tibbles.

Comment: If you want a list `map2(MyList1, MyList2, ~ list(.x, .y))` or `Map(list, MyList1, MyList2)`

Comment: @akrun perfect, this worked. is there a way to convert a list of tibbles into a list of lists so that it can be combined using map or map2? or a way to combine a list of lists with a list of tibbles based on names?

Comment: Yes, you can loop over the names, but here you constructed without a name. i.e. `lapply(names(MyList1), function(nm) list(MyList1[[nm]], MyList2[[nm]]))`

Answer (score 0):

We could loop over the corresponding element of the list and create a nested list

```
library(purrr)
map2(MyList1, MyList2, ~ list(.x, .y))
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
Map(list, MyList1, MyList2)
```

---

If the lists are named, we can also loop over the names of one of the lists (assuming both lists have the same names and have the same length)

```
names(MyList1) <- seq_along(MyList1)
names(MyList2) <- seq_along(MyList2)
lapply(names(MyList1), function(nm) list(MyList1[[nm]], MyList2[[nm]]))
```

---

Or other option is `purrr::transpose`

```
list(MyList1, MyList2) %>%
   purrr::transpose()
```